# Send complete localStorage with jquery (jsonp) to the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, local-storage, jsonp

when i try to send the localStorage to my server i get this error message.

TypeError: 'key' called on an object that does not implement interface Storage.

my code

```
$.ajax({type : "POST", 
    url: "http://domainx.com/api.php", 
    dataType: "jsonp", 
    jsonp: "callback", 
    data:{ls:localStorage}}).done(function(rspData)
{
    alert('done');
}    
}).fail(function(rspData){ alert('fail'); });
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

**Answer:**

```
ls:JSON.stringify(localStorage)
```

Comment: You may need double-quotes around the ls.

Comment: jst posted it on answer so that it will be helpful for other, those who come later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://domainx.com/api.php",
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonp: "callback",
data: {
    ls: JSON.stringify(localStorage)
}
}).done(function(rspData)

{
    alert('done');
}
}).fail(function(rspData) {
    alert('fail');
});
```